# Replace Matching Strings with New Text in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to replace names in the "Name" column with a generic ID and make a new column "research_code", the "Name" column will then be removed.

I do not want to remove duplicates,  but I do want all instances of "Buzz Lightyear" to be replaced by the same integer (i.e 1).  So all "Buzz Lightyears" are "1" all "Twighlight Sparkle's" are "2".  etc

When I run this, I get no errors, but the "research_code" does not persist for some reason.

```
  full_set = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)

  grouped_set = full_set.groupby('Name')
  names = grouped_set.groups.keys()
  idx = 1
  for c in names:
    set_index = str(idx + 1)
    idx = int(set_index) + 1

    replaceables = full_set[(full_set.Name == str(c))]
    for index, row in replaceables.iterrows():

      print(row['Name'])
      print(row['research_code'])
      row['research_code'] = set_index
      print(row['research_code'])
  print(full_set.head)
```

Comment: `full_set['research_code'] = pd.factorize(full_set['Names'])[0]` ?

Comment: can you provide example line of csv?

Comment: @ChrisA that's the ticket.  And thanks for this 'factorize'...more to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Categories can be used.

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3: 
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO

filename = StringIO("""Name
Rahul
Doug
Joe
Buzzlightyear
Twighlight Sparkle
Twighlight Sparkle
Liu
""")

full_set = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
full_set['research_code']  = full_set['Name'].astype('category')
full_set['research_code'] = full_set['research_code'].cat.rename_categories([i for i in range(full_set['research_code'].nunique())])
print(full_set.drop(['Name'], axis=1))
```

That last bit on the list comprehension is a bit gratuitous.  Just rename the categories by providing `rename_categories()` a list of new names (integers in the above Question) that is as long as the number of unique values in the `Names` column.

```
  research_code
0             4
1             1
2             2
3             0
4             5
5             5
6             3
```